# Azure Webjobs vs SSIS packages

Tags: azure, ssis

I have been tasked with creating a scheduled job to first call an api, convert the response to a new format and then pass that data to another api. It doesn't sound like there is any logic in between

The company I work for has a lot of SSIS packages doing a variety of things but also has a healthy Azure platform with a few web jobs running. Several developers on my team have expressed a dislike for SSIS packages so I would like to implement this in Azure, but I want to make sure that is the most reasonable thing to do.

What I am asking for is a pro con list where each option is strong or weak. A good answer will assist readers in making a decision on if their specific situation is best solved using a SSIS package or an Azure webjob, assuming the needed environment is setup for either already.

Comment: I would check azure data factory first: kind of SSIS on azure.

Comment: could use storage queues and azure functions, cheaper for one, used web jobs, data factory and ssis - queues and functions a lot simpler, each function can perform a transformation and then send output to next queue/storage, also can use timer functions to schedule every xx as well.